# sqlalchemy return constant dict in select

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am using sqlalchemy with MySql. I need to return a dict in select. Adding that dict value to fetched data is not an option. Is there any way in sqlalchemy or MySQL by which I can add JSON here

```
 case(
                [
                    (
                        and_(
                            SomeTable.somefield.notin_(
                                constants.SLUGS),
                            OtherTable.otherfield == 1
                        ),
                        [{
                            'label': 'Success',
                            'value': 'True'
                        }]
                    )
                ],
                else_=False
            ).label('status')
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting to JSON ought to work for MySQL (but not for Mariadb):

```
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>>
>>> engine = sa.create_engine('mysql:///test', echo=True, future=True)
>>> with engine.connect() as conn:
...     res = conn.execute(sa.select(sa.case([(True, sa.cast([{'label': 'success', 'value': True}], sa.JSON))], else_=False).label('status')))
...     print(res)
[{"label": "success", "value": true}]
```